# rails - email activation upon user signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-validation, activation

I want the user to click on an activation link before being "activated" or before they can log in with the email/password.

I am not using an gems and want to keep it that way.  My problem is that after the user registers, they can login in without clicking on the activation code.  I have an confirmation_token line and a confirmed line to the model.

user controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
  render "root_path"
 else
  render "new"
 end
end

def confirmed
 user = User.find(:first, :conditions => {:confirmation_token => params[:confirmation_token]})
 if (!params[:confirmation_token].blank?) && user && !user.confirmed?
  user.confirmed!
  self.current_user = user
  flash[:notice] = "Thank you.  You account is now activated."
  redirect_to account_preference_path(current_user)
 else
  flash[:notice] = "Sorry we don't have your email in our database."
  redirect_to root_path
 end
```

end

user model:

```
def confirmed!
 self.confirmed = true
 self.confirmation_token = nil
 save(false) 
end
```

Am I missing anything?  Thanks!

I know there are gems like devise, auth-logic, etc out there but I want to learn how to write it from scratch.  Thanks.

EDIT:

session controller

```
def create
 user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
 if user && user.confirmed == true
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token]
  redirect_to account_path(user.id), :notice => "Welcome, #{user.first_name}"
 else
  flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password."
  render "new"
 end
end
```

Comment: The user signs up and can log in and begin using the site without needing to click on the activation link to confirm their email address.

Comment: Please post the code used to create a new session when the user logs in.

Comment: @ john drummond, see edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, after much trial and  tribulation, I figured it out.  Before, I was redirecting the routes to a new controller where they can edit their password instead of just sending them to the route that just confirms the code.  Silly mistake that cost me a lot of headache, but live and learn.  Thanks everyone who looked into it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for some tutorials to at least guide you through the process, you'll get a better feel for coding rails correctly.

Basically your problem is that your not doing a check to see if the user is confirmed or not on login. One way would be to add this inside your session create method.

```
if user && user.confirmed?
```

The best solution though is probably to use filters like this

```
 before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
```

Then you have an `authenticate` method that checks for a current user, and then have logic that says the current_user can only be a confirmed user. This will check that the user is valid on all the pages that they need to be, instead of only on login.

Comment: I have been playing with the code and I did include to check if it is confirmed.  The issue is that clicking the link is not changing the confirmed boolean from false to true.  it stays false.

Comment: Are you sure its hitting that `confirmed` method ? Might want to throw a debugger in to be sure. Getting from an email link to the confirmation code is the tricky part. Or try loading up the console, creating a new user, then calling confirmed! on him.